# One to many relationships in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having a hard time setting up the basic structure of my databases.

I have products (about 50). Each products is related to one **or more** place(s).

The basic schema would be this (no relation yet)

Products

```
id:integer
name:string
```

Places

```
id:integer
name:string
content:string
```

I first tought I could connect places and products by adding place_id to products and `has_many` `belong_to` in the controllers, but since a product can have more than one place, I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a Product has_many Places and a Place has_many Products your association needs to be many-to-many.

There are two ways to do this in Rails, the most recommended is a join model. You explicitly label the relationship between Products and Places. You could call it ProductLocation or Shop or similar, it would look like this:

```
product_locations:
  product_id
  place_id

class ProductLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :place
end

class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_locations
  has_many :products, :through => :product_locations
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_locations
  has_many :places, :through => :product_locations
end
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many

Answer (score 1):

Just use through connection

ProductsPlaces (new table)

```
product_id
place_id
```

And in models

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :places, :through => :products_places
end

class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, :through => :products_places
end
```

Also there is has_and_belongs_to_many which do in fact the same (with ProductsPlaces table)

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :places
end

class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end
```

But better use through, because has_and_belongs_to_many will be deprecated.

Comment: I'll use `habtm` since the relationship between products and places is simple, no need for extra information. Also, I checked and it won't be deprecated : "DEPRECATED: Using additional attributes on has_and_belongs_to_many 
associations. Instead upgrade your association to be a real join model 
[DHH]" (http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/139047). The function itself will not be deprecated.

Comment: hm Thank you for your comment. It's really interesting because my last team leader said not to use  has_and_belongs_to_many because of deprecation.

Comment: Plus I checked in the rails guide : `The use of extra attributes on the join table in a has_and_belongs_to_many association is deprecated. If you require this sort of complex behavior on the table that joins two models in a many-to-many relationship, you should use a has_many :through association instead of has_and_belongs_to_many.` (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to add `product_id` to `places`.

Product has_many Places

Place belongs_to Product